# Vim Comment Box Macro

Tags: macro, comments

I write comments of the form

```
#############
## Example ##
#############
```

Always one line, always just like that. It's a way of breaking up code more visually. I have lately taken to the following way of typing them out:

1. Type double #, space, the comment, space, double #.
2. Look at the ruler in right hand corner for the horizontal position.
3. `<esc>ki#<esc><the_number_from_step_2_minus_one>.<esc>yyjp` to enter `n` #'s, yank it, and paste it at the bottom.

But even this seems redundant. I would like to define a macro of the form:

```
:let @a='k<n>#i<esc><esc>yyjp<esc>'
```

Where `<n>` is the length of the line I will execute the macro on:

```
## Example ##
```

But I do not know how to record and store the position of the last character on the particular line. Suggestions?

I have found [this suggestion from the vim wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Put_boxes_around_comments_in_code) but I don't want a plugin, and [this from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118249/vim-script-to-surround-multiline-comment-with-comment-character) but this seems like overkill again.

Note: I don't use any plugins and would prefer not to. I literally have none. And a fairly short vimrc (<50 lines after a recent doubling).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t need to know the length of the line. This ought to do it:

```
:let @a = 'yyPVr#jpVr#'
```

I’d also automate the adding of the hashes at the start and end of the middle line:

```
:let @a = "I## \<Esc>A ##\<Esc>yyPVr#jpVr#"
```