# Create indented comment box vim

Tags: comments, text-generation

### Background

I have a code file and I like to place comments inside my code. Sometimes, these comments are boxed:

```
defmodule BananasModule do

    ##############
    # Public API #
    ##############

    def function_blabla do .....
end
```

### Objective

My objective is to have a key sequence (a macro, for example) that surrounds the line I am at with a boxed comment. For example, given the following file:

```
defmodule BananasModule do


    <cursor> Public API

    def function_blabla do .....
end
```

After using some command, I would ideally get:

```
defmodule BananasModule do

    ##############
    # Public API #
    ##############

end
```

Do notice how the comment box *is indented*. This is very important.

### What I have tried

I have tried out the [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter) plugin, but unfortunately it doesn't have this feature.

I have also tried to create a macro [following this discussion](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16989/vim-comment-box-macro):

```
:let @a = "I## \<Esc>A ##\<Esc>yyPVr#jpVr#"
```

But the commend box I get after executing `@a` is not indented:

```
defmodule BananasModule do

####################
    ## Public API ##
####################

end
```

### Problem

Although I feel like I came close, I don't know enough about macros and configurations to make my comment boxes indented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, "put text into a box" is a well-known Vim excercise. I'm not sure where I saw it for the first time, but the most elegant solution, IMO, is to use `:h v_r`

So it becomes:

```
nnoremap <leader># I#<Space><Esc>A<Space>#<Esc>yy2P<C-V>$r#2j.
```

`I#<Space><Esc>` --- add "# " at the start of line

`A<Space>#<Esc>` --- add " #" at the end of line

`yy2P` --- make 2 copies of the current line (so we have three identical `# text #` lines)

`<C-V>$r#` --- change the top line into `#####`

`2j.` -- and the same for bottom line

Comment: This does not help with the indentation problem I currently have.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix "The box" has the same indent as "Public API" had before

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: Very nice answer! The Vim golfer in me wants to do `Y2Pvg_r#2j.` for the last part. Using `P` makes the `k` unnecessary. Applying the `r#` to the last character (rather than end of line) makes it repeatable with `.`. nitpick: You're missing a `#` in explanation for the `A` command.

Comment: @filbranden Thank you, I improve my answer.

Comment: If anyone is in the mood for golf: [Box it](http://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/5c742a5a50bdf70006d43280)

Answer (score 1):

This can be best accomplished with [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) and [vim-snippet](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets).

vim-snippets provides a snippet [`box`](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/all.snippets#L22) which can create a bounded box. It is just what you want. I have tested on a Python source file and it works great. Give it a try.

Comment: I could not find any `snippet box` in ultisnips repo linked above.

Comment: @Dilawar The `box` snippet is in `all.snippets` file [here](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/all.snippets#L22).

Comment: Thanks, would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The [LudoPinelli/comment-box.nvim](https://github.com/LudoPinelli/comment-box.nvim) neovim plugin seems to address this use-case.